# Aggregate option in SQL Server CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following data in a `#temp` table:

```
Id  code       Fname       CompanyId    FieldName         Value
----------------------------------------------------------------
465 00133   JENN WILSON       1           ERA              1573
465 00133   JENN WILSON       1           ESHIFTALLOW      3658
465 00133   JENN WILSON       1           NETPAY          51560
```

I want to do following operation i.e

- One Row will be addition on two columns i.e `ERA +  ESHIFTALLOW`
- Other Row will be subtraction & addition on three columns i.e  `NETPAY - ERA +  ESHIFTALLOW`

I had tried using `case` statement in SQL Server.

This is the query

```
Select 
    Id, Code, Fname, CompanyID, Company, FieldNameNew,
    Sum(Value) Value 
Into 
    #temp2
from 
    (select 
         Id, Code, Fname, CompanyID, Company, Value,
         case 
            when FieldName in ('OT', 'EONCALLALLOW', 'ESHIFTALLOW', 'FOT', 'EUNIALLOW', 'ESECALLOW', 'ERA') 
               then 'OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA'
            when FieldName in ('NETPAY') 
               then 'NETPAY-OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA'      
            else FieldName 
         end, 
         FieldNameNew
     from 
         #temp) A
group by 
    Id, Code, Fname, CompanyID, Company, FieldNameNew
```

Using above query im able to get partial result

```
Id  code          Fname  CompanyId   FieldNameNew                                                   Value
465 00133   JENN WILSON   1       NETPAY-OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA    51560  //INCORRECT Actual value should be (51560-5231) = 46329
465 00133   JENN WILSON   1       OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA           5231 //CORRECT
```

Addition is working fine but while doing subtraction in NETPAY it is not working

> NETPAY-OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA 
>   value =     51560 //INCORRECT Actual value should be (51560-5231) = 46329
>
> OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA
>   Value=       5231 //CORRECT

Comment: The `THEN` expression looks like a string.  How is this being used/converted to a number?

Answer (score 2):

You have correct logic but wrong formula :

This is wrong way

```
**NETPAY-OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA**
```

You must use

```
**NETPAY-OT-EONCALLALLOW-ESHIFTALLOW-FOT-EUNIALLOW-ESECALLOW-ERA**
```

Or

```
**NETPAY-(OT+EONCALLALLOW+ESHIFTALLOW+FOT+EUNIALLOW+ESECALLOW+ERA)**
```

Comment: You are using formula for field name only and sum function for calculating values. Totally wrong logic you have.

Comment: thanks pooja i got the solution i was using wrong logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939551/aggregate-function-on-multiple-columns-in-sql-server